# Border Selection in complex 3d-models

Tags: selection-tools

I have a problem  with the selection tools in Blender 2.79b. Maybe someone can help me :)

I have a complex city model and I wanna select a few buildings to export them in a x3d-model. Unfortunately not all relevant objects are selected when I am using the border selection tool (see picture).

[image]

Is this a well known bug of this blender version? Or can you give me some advice how to solve my problem? I am not able to use the new Blender version because of the different material system. Do you now an other 3D-software that is able to import a really complex Collada-model and export it to x3D?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which differences of the new material system do you mean? Selecting the objects with a selection tool has nothing to do with materials. Also as the answer suggests, the problem here is that some objects or their origins are not visible behind other objects and this is most likely the reason they don't get selected. I doubt this worked much different in previous Blender versions.

Answer (score 2):

To select everything use the hotkey a.

Alternatively you can also go into x-ray mode under viewport shading->x-ray to help your selection.